# Setting math font with multirow bigdelim

Tags: multirow, bigdelim

I am trying to produce this table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Cooljazz}[Scale = .85] 
\DeclareMathVersion{cj}
\setmathfont[version=cj]{cooljazz.ttf}
\newenvironment{tabchav}{\mathversion{cj}}{}

\begin{document}


Some irrelevant text

\begin{tabchav}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ccccc}
        \toprule
        Grupo & Scores & i & & Ordens\\
        \midrule
        Ex-fumador & 1 & 1 & &1.0\\
        Ex-fumador & 2 & 2 &\rdelim \}{2}{*}[$\frac{2+3}{2}$] &2.5\\
        Ex-fumador & 2 & 3 & &2.5\\
        Fumador Regular & 3 & 4 & \rdelim\}{5}{*}[$\frac{4+5+6+7+8}{5}$] & 6.0\\
        Fumador Regular & 3 & 5 & &6.0\\
        Fumador Ocasional & 3 & 6 & &6.0\\
        Fumador Ocasional & 3 & 7 & &6.0\\
        Ex-fumador & 3 & 8 & &6.0\\
        Fumador Regular & 4 & 9 &\rdelim\}{5}{*}[$\frac{9+10+11+12+13}{5}$]  &11.0\\
        Fumador Regular & 4 & 10 & &11.0\\
        Fumador Ocasional & 4 & 11 & &11.0\\
        Fumador Ocasional & 4 & 12 & &11.0\\
        Fumador Ocasional & 4 & 13 & &11.0\\
        Fumador Regular & 5 & 14 & &14.0\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabchav}

\end{document}
```

I do get the table, but I am puzzled that the math font is `lmr`and not Cool jazz as defined:

[image: Table with cool jazz font]

Any idea of what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `mathspec` support math versions to begin with? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Need to add   `\setmathfont[range={"58-"FFFF}]{Latin Modern Math}` before the `\begin{tabular}`:

[image]